# How to disable MFA authentication in aws-amplify?

Tags: vue.js, aws-amplify

I'm using AWS amplify on my vuejs app, but I don't need the MFA authentication.
I'm trying to disable it with `import { Auth } from 'aws-amplify';
Auth.setPreferredMFA(user, 'NOMFA');` but it doesn't work.

someone know how to disable it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with the Amplify CLI. It should propose you the following option:

```
Multifactor authentication (MFA) user login options: (Use arrow keys)
❯ OFF 
  - ON (Required for all logins, can not be enabled later) (Disabled)
  OPTIONAL (Individual users can use MFA) 
  I want to learn more.
```

If you already enable Auth configuration, you have to update it with the following command: `amplify auth update`

Comment: Thanks Johan,  I've already a auth configuration, and after install `npm install -g @aws-amplify/cli` I tried to `amplify auth update

`  but the command is not found. 
I thinks your first proposition is best solution for the moment. I'm gonna try to remake a new auth configuration and make the `Multifactor authentication (MFA) user login options` OFF.